# Android podcast app similar to iOS default

Tags: android, podcast

So I recently made the switch from iPhone to Android, and one of the things I miss now is the default podcast app on iPhone, as in my eyes it was the perfect podcast app. So I'm wondering if there are any apps similar to it on the Play Store? I've tried Stitcher and Podcast Addict, but they have too much "fuzz" about them imo. I just want to search for the podcasts I follow, and add them to a folder that automatically downloads new episodes. And then, this is the thing that it seems no podcast app is doing, when an episode is finished, just go to the next episode and play that. If I started the current episode from a specific podcast, then go to the next in that list, if I started it from the main list of all podcasts, then go to the next episode in that list.

It would also be nice if it was possible to sort by published date both asc and desc, as I often go to older podcasts and start from the beginning.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. I'm willing to pay for the app, as long as it does these things.

Answer (score 2):

I personally use [Pocket Casts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=au.com.shiftyjelly.pocketcasts) (non free).

You should find the ability to add podcasts for automated download, automated cleanup, variable retention periods (both global and individual), sorting by release date (asc & desc).

Comment: I second pocket cast. Extra one-off payment of USD9 if you want to use the web version, but I think it is worth it.